# Having trouble with creating a timetable

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to make a timetable using data in a MySQL table that has the day, start and durtaion of each event.

My logic at the moment goes like this.

Find all events with monday, put in an array for monday
Find all events with tuesday, put in an array for tuesday

etc

then i run a for each loop on each array to go through each time slot in the day (9-5) and if it matches the current event, create a table cell, if not create and empty cell and finally if the event duration is longer than 1 slott then dont put anything. here is my code for the above:

```
function createTableEvent($day,$previousfinish)
{
$completeDay = '';
$day = explode(',',$day);

        $ev = $day[0];
        $start = $day[1];
        $end =  $day[2];
        $event = "<div class=\"table_event\">$ev<br>Starts:$start<br>Ends:$end<br></div>";

    $times= array('09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17');

    //TIMES
    foreach ($times as $time)
    {


         if($start == $time.":00" && $previousfinish == !)
          {
        $completeDay .= "<td class=\"$time\" colspan=\"$end\">
                <div class=\"table_event\">$event</div></td>"; 
        $previousfinish = $end;
          } 
         else if($previousfinish > 1
             {
             }
              else
        {
        $completeDay .= "<td class=\"$time\" colspan=\"1\"></td>"; 
        }

    }   
        return $completeDay;        

}
```

The reason i wanna skip the cell if it is more than 1 is because if an event runs over more than one block, i set the column span to the duration of the event, there for it shhouldnt put a cell in for the next time if the previous event was longer than one block.

My output works for single hour events however not when a day has say 1 2 hour event and a 2nd 1 hour event. My code still makes the extra cells for the times that should be empty.

Any input or help would be very useful

Answer (score 1):

The obvious things I notices were:

- The second if statement (right after the 'else')'s condition is not
  followed by a closing ')'.
- I couldn't make out if this is wanted, but there are no commands to
  whenever this condition is met
- At the first condition inside the for loop you compare the
  $previousfinish parameter to '!'. Is this really what you want to do?
  Did you mean to compare it to '1'?

Other things I noticed is that if the last condition is met, you put the event time but not the event name (as you did in the first place).

I tried to further investigatethe problem, but it's bit hard, since I don't know what data is passed to the function in the arguments.

I suggest you fix the above problems and see if this fixes you problem.
If not, I would be happy to look further into this issue, if you supply a sample data being passed to the function.

Also, I re-arranged the code for readability, if you find it better -

```
<?php

function createTableEvent($day, $previousfinish)
{
    $completeDay = '';

    list ($ev, $start, $end) = explode(',',$day);

    $event = "<div class=\"table_event\">$ev<br>Starts:$start<br>Ends:$end<br></div>";

        //TIMES
    foreach (array('09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17') as $time)
    {
        if ($start == ($time.":00") && $previousfinish == !)
            {
                $completeDay .= "<td class=\"$time\" colspan=\"$end\">
                    <div class=\"table_event\">$event</div></td>";
                $previousfinish = $end;
            }
            else if($previousfinish > 1)
                {
                }
            else
            {
                $completeDay .= "<td class=\"$time\" colspan=\"1\"></td>";
            }
        }

    return $completeDay;
}
?>
```